# Invoke asynchronous method call from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I'm currently working on a web site which involves a data upload process. The file is currently uploaded to the server method is called (in app_code) where ultimately a DTS package is called (via a web method) to load the data into a database and perform some validation on it.

The client has specified that they don't want to have to wait for the DTS package to execute (execution time is less than 5 minutes) so it appears that I need to call the method asynchronously. The user will probably logout or close the browser window while this task is running so I believe I'm unable to run this on an asp.net thread.

Can anyone give me some guidance as to the best way to proceed on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, all you need to do is launch a thread or a method invoker and it will operate as intended, even if the users session end.

We use this same ability to manage very large data processing tasks in our web based CMS.